# In PHP, how do you get the text offset of a timezone

Tags: php, timezone, timezone-offset

How do you get the timezone offset text?  For example if I pass in:

```
America/New_York
```

...I would like to receive back:

```
-04:00
```

Comment: I believe this question and the answer I provided after research (found in the answer) was voted down because it didn't meed this criteria found in the tip of the downvote button: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful".  Ironically it's the kind of question/answer I prefer.  Short, clear and to the point, not muddied by a bunch of crap showing OP's unsuccessful attempt that we find so often (mind you, not that that's inappropriate).  Interestingly it meets the criteria of SO's stated purpose: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/28857 .  esp the "fast"

Answer (score -1):

I created a function called getTimezoneOffsetText

```
<?php
    function getTimezoneOffsetText($timezone){
        date_default_timezone_set( "UTC" );
        $daylight_savings_offset_in_seconds = timezone_offset_get(timezone_open($timezone), new DateTime());
        $mod = $daylight_savings_offset_in_seconds/60 % 60;
        $min = abs($mod);

        return sprintf('%+03d', $daylight_savings_offset_in_seconds/60/60) . ':' . sprintf('%02d', $min);
}

$offset1 = 'America/New_York';
$offset2 = 'Asia/Kabul';
$offset3 = 'Asia/Kathmandu';
$offset4 = 'Israel';
$offset5 = 'Greenwich';
$offset6 = 'America/Caracas';

echo '<pre>';
echo $offset1 . ":\t" . getTimezoneOffsetText($offset1) . '<br/>';
echo $offset2 . ":\t\t" . getTimezoneOffsetText($offset2) . '<br/>';
echo $offset3 . ":\t\t" . getTimezoneOffsetText($offset3) . '<br/>';
echo $offset4 . ":\t\t\t" . getTimezoneOffsetText($offset4) . '<br/>';
echo $offset5 . ":\t\t" . getTimezoneOffsetText($offset5) . '<br/>';
echo $offset6 . ":\t" . getTimezoneOffsetText($offset6) . '<br/>';
echo '</pre>';
```

It generates this data:

```
America/Caracas:    -04:30
Asia/Kabul:         +04:30
Asia/Kathmandu:     +05:45
Israel:             +03:00
Greenwich:          +00:00
America/New_York:   -04:00
```

Note that it gets half hour and other "non-standard" timezones such as Caracas, Kabul and Kathmandu.  I'm curious though if there is already a function that exists that accomplishes this.

Comment: Is this part of your question? Or an answer?